# match against in mysql in live server is not working

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

```
Select * from admintasks where MATCH (User_name) AGAINST('murali');
```

This query is working fine on localhost, but while running on the live server it is showing an error:

> MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 sec)

Comment: This is not the error.

Comment: check the value in ft_min_word_length in live server. In debian its usually in /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: That's obviously not an error message. You are missing at least: 1) MySQL version 2) `CREATE TABLE` code (stripping non-related columns and including engine, full-text index definition and collation) 3) A description of your data: total rows, expected matches, maybe a sample match.

Comment: why don't you use 'Like' instead of match ?

Comment: actually I need to get a single value from multiple values separated by comma,

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try Like instead match

```
Select * from admintasks where User_name LIKE '%murali%';
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). (Query took 0.0003 sec)
```

is the output when the **queried result-set does not contain any values** in it....Your query is working just fine mate, may be you need some better `where` clause to fetch data!!!